# Forecasting out-of-sample with exogenous variables using SARIMAX in Statsmodels -python

Tags: python, sarimax

I've tried running statsmodels SARIMAX code in Python but I keep getting:

"ValueError: Out-of-sample operations in a model with a regression component require additional exogenous values via the `exog` argument."

Both my endog ['Oil_(Sm3)'] and exog ['Water_(Sm3)'] variables have the same shape (91, 2).

I'm stumped!

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've added more code.  Does it suffice now?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [statsmodels ARIMA forecast without future values of exogenous variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61765604/statsmodels-arima-forecast-without-future-values-of-exogenous-variable)

Answer (score 2):

[image: SARIMAX Prediction]

I basically added the "exog = test_exog" component to the .predict() line

Comment: Please paste the actual code instead of a screenshot of it.